Disable a chunk of code for old simulators in swift?
I have a "request review" alert:
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)

The problem is it hangs the iPhone 15.x simulator so I decided to disable it.
But there is another problem - disabling of simulator is implemented with macro:
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
   ...
#endif

and disabling for particular iOS versions is implemented with the attributes @available or #available.
How to combine macro with these attributes? Or are there more convenient ways to achieve this?
My current code is:
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }
#else
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
#endif


You can always write your own global variables that wraps these "macros" (technically they are not macros).
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    let isSimulator = true
#else
     let isSimulator = false
#endif

var ios16Available: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}

Then you can do
if ios16Available || !isSimulator {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}

You can avoid declaring ios16Available if you can accept an empty if statement (I find this horrendous):
if #unavailable(iOS 16), isSimulator {} else {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}

If it is possible to return immediately, a guard works perfectly:
guard #unavailable(iOS 16), isSimulator else {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
    return
}

